# "Procedural" Design Pattern for DoThis->ThenThis->AndThenThis

Tags: design-patterns

I'm trying to find a useful design pattern that simulates something like this following:

```
DoThis()->ThenThis()->FinallyDoThis() then print "Hello world"
```

`ThenThis()` doesn't run unless `DoThis()` passes. And `FinallyDoThis()` won't run unless `ThenThis()` and `DoThis()` both pass. If all the methods methods pass, then it prints "Hello world".

Is there an existing design pattern that would fit nicely to this? I've been investigating the usage of monads, but not sure if they are applicable to this case.

Comment: You mean in a functional programming language?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you are looking for design pattern. I think it's [Chain-of-responsibility pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern)

Comment: +1: except the chain continues until failure instead of continuing until success.  But certainly similar implementation and concept.

Comment: Thank you for actually mentioning a design pattern which was the original request.

Answer (score 4):

Without knowing your language, you could put it in an `if` statement if the language `if` statement short-circuits.  Then have each function return true or false:

```
if( foo() && bar() && baz() ){
    System.out.println( "hello world" );
}
```